# Craft Error Logging not doing anything?

Tags: logging, logs

I have a plugin called EducatorEntriesPlugin, and in the controller of the plugin, I have a method called actionExportEducator. In this method, I am logging an error using the code below, but when the action is called, the error is not logged into the log file, why might this be?

```
Craft::log("There was an error")
```

I also did `EducatorEntriesPlugin::log`, that doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn `devMode` on https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode

If you want the errors to log regardless of `devMode` or not, pass in `true` as the third parameter, e.g.:

`Craft::log("There was an error", LogLevel::Info, true);`

https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-log-errors-warnings-and-info-in-my-plugins-to-a-craft-log-file

Comment: I tried this and still am getting nothing in the log. In fact I haven't had anything show up in the log for nearly a month. Any other ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Daniel: What have you tried? Guessing that part of your plugin isn't firing. I'm assuming you're not the original poster since it was marked as solved? You might want to try posting your code in a new topic and we'll give you some help.

Comment: I have the same issue as @DanielBoggs, no matter what I do,   Craft::log("test", LogLevel::Info, true); Never prints to the log.  although the log is filling up with all kinds of info while running in devMode.